# First request to a new ReplicaSet times out

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster on AWS, set up with `kops`.

I set up a Deployment that runs an Apache container and a Service for the Deployment (type: LoadBalancer).

When I update the deployment by running `kubectl set image ...`, as soon as the first pod of the new `ReplicaSet` becomes ready, the *first couple* of requests to the service time out.

Things I have tried:

- I set up a `readinessProbe` on the pod, works.
- I ran `curl localhost` on a pod, works.
- I performed a DNS lookup for the service, works.
- If I `curl` the IP returned by that DNS lookup inside a pod, the first request will timeout.  This tells me it's not an ELB issue.

It's really frustrating since otherwise our Kubernetes stack is working great, but every time we deploy our application we run the risk of a user timing out on a request.

Comment: so it fails when you try to use service IP, what if you curl the pod IP (not localhost) ? is this a universal issue regardless of what you run in the container (ie. static nginx page) or only for this apache image ?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging, I think I've solved this issue.

TL;DR; Apache has to exit gracefully.

#### I found a couple of related issues:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47725
- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/69
- [504 Gateway Timeout - Two EC2 instances with load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542936/504-gateway-timeout-two-ec2-instances-with-load-balancer)

#### Some more things I tried:

- Increase the KeepAliveTimeout on Apache, didn't help.
- Ran `curl` on the pod IP and node IPs, worked normally.
- Set up an `externalName` selector-less service for a couple of external dependencies, thinking it might have something to do with DNS lookups,   didn't help.

### The solution:

I set up a [`preStop`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) lifecycle hook on the pod to gracefully terminate Apache to run `apachectl -k graceful-stop`

The issue (at least from what I can tell), is that when pods are taken down on a deployment, they receive a `TERM` signal, which causes apache to [immediately kill](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html#term) all of its children. This *might* cause a race condition where `kube-proxy` still sends some traffic to pods that have received a `TERM` signal but not terminated completely.

Also got some help from this [blog post](https://pracucci.com/graceful-shutdown-of-kubernetes-pods.html) on how to set up the hook.

I also recommend increasing the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` in the [PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#podspec-v1-core) so apache has enough time to exit gracefully.